# How can I update the child, when it calls a callback of the master?

Tags: react-native

My parent renders a list (funcional child component)
If some item of the list is deleted, the callback deleteItem is executed in the parent.
But neither the parent nor the child are going to re-render, which is my problem.
I tried to simplify my problem by just showing the variable update.

```
export default function Master({ navigation, route }) {

  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(0);

  const deleteItem = function(coral) {
      setUpdate(update+1);
  }
      ..
  return (
         <DeletableList
              itemHeight={100}
              listdata={data}
              onPressCallback={openItem}
              onDeleteCallback={deleteItem}
              getItemCallback={getItem}
              countitems={data.length}
              update={update}
          />
      );
```

The list in the child is only rendered initially and does not react on changed triggered from the master.

```
const DeletableList = (props) => {
   ...

    return (
    <View>
    <Text>child: {props.update}</Text>
     ..
    )
```

Comment: whats the component of DeletableList? is Flatlist?

Comment: its a SwipeListView, which is build upon a FlatList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try update ***the state of data array***  by filtering it and remove item that deleted

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);


const handleOnItemDeleted = (itemThatDeleted) => {
    setData(
        data.filter(
            x => x.id !== itemThatDeleted.id
        )
    );
}


<Listcomponent data={data} />
```